# Filter/delete polygons if they are surrounded by other polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers

I've been looking for a method to extract polygons (here in green) witch are surrounded by other polygons (red ) in QGIS. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Would this be the same as polygons that don't touch the edges of the "image" except possibly at a single point?

Comment: are they holes in the red polygon or green ones contained in it?

Comment: @IanTurton I use OSM data of landuse types. green is farming, red is residential. So yes, here the red one has holes (not overlapping polygons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run "Delete Holes" algorithm from processing toolbox on your red polygons (the one surrounding the smaller ones) and choose a very large threshold to ensure it does not have any holes anymore
2. Run "Extract by location", choose the small sourrounded polygons as first input, `are within` as predicate and the just generated deleted-holes-layer as second input

Comment: 1) works just fine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) tool with this expression.

```
with_variable(
    'neighbours',
    overlay_touches(
        'layer_id',
        "Name",
        "Name" = 'Red'
    ),
    array_count(
        @neighbours,
        'Red'
    ) = array_length(
            @neighbours
        ) and 
        array_length(
            @neighbours
        ) and "Name" = 'Green'
)
```

replace `layer_id` with your layer name or id, every `Name` with the name containing the "color" information and every `Red` / `Green` with the respective color.